# How to label the value increments on the x and y axis

Tags: axis

I need to label the x and y axis with points like \sqrt{5} and pi on the axis correctly and proportionally to the line, how do I do this

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us an example document with your diagram. Then we can more easy help you. Usually help to write fore example `xticklabels={ ,$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, 0, $\pi$, $2\pi$, },` . Read the package documentation!